# Basic EMG classification (time series)

Tags: time-series, classification, signal-processing

I'm trying to learn how to classify bio-signals, and I'm starting with EMG signals from hand gestures, since a lot of data exists on this topic. My problem is understanding how test the probability of a new EMG recording to belong to a class.

I've read the article *"A robust, real-time control scheme for multifunction myoelectric control (2003)"*, where they divide the signal into e.g. 200 ms overlapping intervals, and use majority vote to decide what gesture the hand measured made. They use features like: **mean absolute value, zero-crossings, slope sign changes** and **waveform length**. I've seen others use SD, mean and min/max.

I want to replicate something similar to gain experience, and then move on to other muscles not explored yet. To start with, i wish to make a for 4 class problem, that recognizes which finger is bent from one EMG recording.

**My questions is**: when i extracted the features, how do i make a classifier? i.e., how do i "train" it, and test for the probability for a piece of the signal to belong each of the classes? For instance, let's say i have 100 EMG recordings and the zero crossings for these. I now record a new signal; how do i calculate the probability of this signal to belong to each of e.g. 4 classes?

I've had linear algebra, introductory machine learning (**not** including time series), introductory statistics, and just started a course in signal analysis. So i know some basics, but i have absolute no idea what to do when data is time dependent.

I'm most proficient in MatLab, but if python or R is a lot better for some reason, i could learn to use these instead.